# Erro na instalação do Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio

Eu tentei instalar o VS Express 2013 for Windows Desktop no meu notebook que havia acabado de ser formatado e instalado o Windows 8.

Recebi uma mensagem no setup reclamando de pre requisitos.

Antes de começar a instalar os pre requisitos, decidi atualizar o OS para o Windows 8.1.
Ainda sim o problema persistia, mas dessa vez o setup pedia por outro pre requisito.

Fui instalando na medida que ele (o setup) foi pedindo... Até que chegou uma hora que eu fiquei nervoso e instalei o VS 2013 Ultimate with Blend (na esperança de instalar todos os pre requisitos necessarios).
Depois dessa instalação rodei novamente o setup do Express for Windows Desktop e agora o setup simplesmente diz algo como "Não pôde instalar o VS Express 2013 for Windows Desktop: Argumento Inválido", ou "Falha na execução" (não me lembro do erro exato, vou editar a pergunta quando chegar em casa, mas não foge muito disso não).

Alguém ja sofreu com isso ou tem idéia de como resolver?

PS: o VS Ultimate with Blend funciona...

Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Caso o seu arquivo seja

```
wdexpress_full.exe
```

Verifique se o MD5 é igual a esse:

```
b87dd4ded93751c69d4bc82836544b5f
```

Comment: É esse arquivo, mas o MD5 é diferente: b97fad7462144c56c2637520457b71fa

Comment: Por algum fenômeno extraordinario, cheguei em casa, rodei o setup e funcionou! hahaha Obrigado! =)